# Compile Program Using Opencv Libraries

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to compile a program using this opencv module
http://xanthippi.ceid.upatras.gr/people/evangelidis/ecc/

I'm using the source here which includes "cc_image_registration.cpp" utility program
http://xanthippi.ceid.upatras.gr/people/evangelidis/ecc/data/ecc_opencv.zip

The source includes

- ecc.cpp
- ecc.h
- ecc_image_registration.cpp
- ... some sample files

I'm trying to compile their standalone utility which is "cc_image_registration.cpp"

When I run

```
g++ -B/usr/exp/ecc/ecc.h -I/usr/include/opencv  ecc_image_registration.cpp $(pkg-config opencv --libs) -o ecc
```

I get back

```
/tmp/cceULny7.o: In function `main':
ecc_image_registration.cpp:(.text+0x91f): undefined reference to `cvFindTransform(_IplImage const*, _IplImage const*, CvMat*, WARP_MODE, CvTermCriteria const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

cvFindTransform is defined in ecc.h.

I don't normally work with C++ but I'd just like to compile this utility and call it from Python.

Comment: .. just be a bit sceptic about using code from 2008, which is all written in opencv's deprecated c-api...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I have to include ecc.cpp as well. This worked.

```
g++ -I/usr/include/opencv  ecc_image_registration.cpp ecc.cpp $(pkg-config opencv --libs) -o ecc
```